# How to run both a client and API on the same express server?

Tags: express

I have an React/Redux app that makes use of an API endpoint. I'm currently rendering the React/Redux client on one server and my API on another - both use express. How can I run them both on the same server. Would I just serve a static dir for my client and add in GET/POST/etc. for the server like so:

```
//...

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    //...
  })

app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    //...
  })

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've suggested should work fine, which is outlined in the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), but if you're gonna be serving static files I'd recommend putting them behind an [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) reverse proxy. Nginx is awesome at serving up static files, plus if you decide to use HTTPS later on, you'll just need a cert for the machine running Nginx and the rest of the communication can be done via HTTP.

Basically you'd install Nginx and setup your config to look something like this:

```
upstream api_pool {
    server localhost:3000;
    # feel free to add as many other servers to this pool as you'd like
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /www/static_stuff;

    location / {
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api_pool;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Restart Nginx so the config changes take effect, place all your static stuff in /www/static_stuff (or whatever you decided to make your root dir) and then start up your express server on port 3000.

Now, let's say you drop a file called style.css into /www/static_stuff. Pointing a web browser to localhost/style.css will serve the file /www/static_stuff/style.css. Pointing a web browser to localhost/api/some_express_route will be just like pointing a web browser to localhost:3000/some_express_route.

Warning! I didn't try this config file, but if you decide to take the Nginx route and it doesn't work, let me know and I'd be happy to create a test environment to get you up and running.